# ionic3 enable/disable button programmatically when ion list is full/empty

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I have a searchbar for which I check for input events and then filter firebase data.
This is the html code:

```
<ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)" placeholder="Add tag ... "></ion-searchbar>
<ion-list>
<ion-item *ngFor="let tag of tagList">
<h2> {{ tag.name }} </h2>
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

and this is the ts code:

```
getItems(searchbar) {
 // Reset items back to all of the items
this.initializeItems();

 // set q to the value of the searchbar
var q = searchbar.srcElement.value;

// if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
if (!q) {
return;
}

this.tagList = this.tagList.filter((v) => {
if(v.name && q) {
  if (v.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(q.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
 });

}
```

This code works well, but now I would like to enable a button whenever the list loaded on the view is empty, while keeping it disabled when there's at least one element loaded. The code for the button is this one:

```
  <button ion-button [disabled]="!isEnabled">Add tag</button>
```

I change the value of `isEnabled` to true or false in the `getItems()` method, this way:

```
if (this.tagList.length==0){
console.log('No elements ')
this.isEnabled=true;
  } else {
    console.log('Elements ')
    this.isEnabled=false;
  }
```

but the button remains disabled (when first entering the page, isEnabled is marked as false by default).
The logs are shown correctly when I write something in the searchbar, that is whenever I enter a letter the console outputs "elements" or "no elements" depending if the list has elements or not, but the button remains disabled.
How do I solve that? Am I missing something?

EDIT: here's the code where I set `isEnabled` :

```
getItems(searchbar) {
  // Reset items back to all of the items
  this.initializeItems();

  // set q to the value of the searchbar
  var q = searchbar.srcElement.value;
  this.textSearch = q;

  // if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
  if (!q) {
    return;
  }

  this.tagList = this.tagList.filter((v) => {
  if(v.name && q) {
     if (v.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(q.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
     return true;
  }
  return false;
   }
 });

 if (this.tagList.length==0){
   this.isEnabled = true;
 } else{
   this.isEnabled = false;
 }
}
```

Comment: console.log(this.isEnabled) in else part and see whats its returning

Answer (score 16):

As we talked about in the comments, please edit your post to include the entire method where you set the `isEnabled` property so we can figure out what could be going on, but in the meantime, replace

```
<button ion-button [disabled]="!isenabled">Add tag</button>
```

by

```
<button ion-button [disabled]="tagList && tagList.length > 0">Add tag</button>
```

or what would be equivalent by using the elvis operator:

```
<button ion-button [disabled]="tagList?.length > 0">Add tag</button>
```

Comment: Sorry, in the question I mistyped the variable name, but in my code the name is correctly typed as isEnabled, and it doesn't work :\

Comment: Oh, I see... What happens if you change that button for this: `<button ion-button [disabled]="tagList && tagList.length > 0">Add tag</button>`?

Comment: Ok, the second way worked. Thanks. Any clue why the first one didn't? It seemed ok to me

Comment: Well, that's progress lol could you please update the post, with the entire method where you set the `isEnabled` property?.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable it checking the array length

```
<button ion-button [disabled]="tagList.length > 0">Add tag</button>
```

With this code you'll need to initiate the variable when declaring it, or it'll throw an error, when declaring do

```
public tagList: any[] = [];
```

With this you can remove the `isEnabled` variable and the piece of code whose checks if it has items or don't.

Hope this helps :D